# Difference betweeen filter and equal in a measure

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I can't figure out the difference between the 2 following measures, returning the same result ?

```
TestFIlter = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(BDD_Index[Conso]),
    FILTER(
        Plan_comptage_EDV,
        Plan_comptage_EDV[Plan CPT] = 1
    )
)
```

and

```
TestEQUAL = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(BDD_Index[Conso]),
    Plan_comptage_EDV[Plan CPT] = 1
)
```

Which is the better one ? Any performance impact ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is the better one. The first filters an entire table which is bad practice (you should only filter columns). The second is syntax sugar and internally rewritten as:

```
TestEQUAL = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(BDD_Index[Conso]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Plan_comptage_EDV[Plan CPT]),
        Plan_comptage_EDV[Plan CPT] = 1
    )
)
```

Further reading:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filter-arguments-in-calculate/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk-7gBt9CDE&list=RDCMUCcc21gBGNJwZM_eDEByeN-Q&index=4